# How can retrieve a file from window.PERSISTENT storage?

Tags: javascript, html5-filesystem

I have downloaded a image file using third party api and written in window persistent storage 
name called pogo.png how can I retrieve and execute.

Comment: What's the third party API? Could you post the code you used to download and write pogo.png?

Answer (score 1):

For debugging the Filesystem API, you have a few options:

1.Use this [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html5-filesystem-explorer/nhnjmpbdkieehidddbaeajffijockaea) to view/remove files.
2.See the tips here: [tips](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Debugging-the-Filesystem-API) That includes viewing stored files very easily using the filesystem: URLs.
3.Drop the Filesystem Playground demo (http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/filesystem/filer.js/demos/index.html) into your origin. You can use that to view/rename/delete files/folders easily.
4.Chrome DevTools now has support for the Filesystem API in Chrome Canary...at least viewing the files stored under an origin. To use that, right now you need to enable Developer Tools experiments in about:flags, restart, hit the gear in the devtools (lower right corner), and enable the 'FileSystem inspection' under the experimental tab.